# What percentage of my data is less than a specific time fram

Tags: excel, percentage

I am trying to find the percentage of the whole that is less than 24 hours. I have a case closure date which is represented by the case completion date - the case entry date. I need to find out what percentage of my data is more than 24 hours and what percentage is less than or equal to 24 hours. The formula I have now to give me a case closure date is

```
=IF(H2-E2<=TIME(23,59,59)+TIME(0,0,1),"<24 hours",H2-E2)
```

What formula do I use to get a percentage for the needed data?

```
Case Entry Date Case Received Date  First Response Date Case Completion Date    Case Closure 
3/1/2017 9:54   3/1/2017 9:54   3/1/2017 9:56   3/1/2017 9:59   <24 hours
3/1/2017 11:38  3/1/2017 11:38  3/1/2017 11:46  3/1/2017 11:47  <24 hours
3/13/2017 8:15  3/13/2017 8:15  3/13/2017 8:26  3/20/2017 11:01 7
3/17/2017 11:17 3/17/2017 11:17 3/17/2017 11:23 3/20/2017 10:09 3
3/17/2017 11:17 3/17/2017 11:17 3/17/2017 11:23 3/20/2017 10:09 3
```

Comment: pseudocode: COUNTIF(="<24 hours") / COUNT * 100 ?

Comment: when I am using this formula, it is giving me an error message. How is the formula supposed to be read?

Comment: Try `=COUNTIF(E2:E6, "<24 hours") / (ROWS(E2:E6) * 100)` assuming `Case Closure` is in column E and data starts at row 2